# How to get the 1 element before & after an element in a set (Java)

Tags: java, set

Given a set of strings `(1.0 1.1 1.2 3.0 3.1 4.0)`, I want to be able to get the 1 element before and the 1 element after a specific item.

For example:

```
1.0 --> 1.1
1.1 --> 1.0, 1.2
1.2 --> 1.1, 3.0
4.0 --> 3.1
```

I specifically have a `NavigableSet<String>` here, but in theory could change this to a better fit, if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`NavigableSet#higher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#higher(E)) to get the first element strictly greater than a particular one (i.e., the next element) and [`NavigableSet#lower`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#lower(E)) to get the first element strictly less than some element (i.e., the previous element). Both of these methods return `null` if there is no such element in the set.

```
System.out.println(set.higher("1.0"));//"1.1"
System.out.println(set.lower("1.0"));//null
```

[Demo!](https://ideone.com/uVOL85)

Comment: Is there a simple solution if I suddenly need the 2 or 3 surrounding?

Answer (score 2):

you need methods lower() and higher();